# Show that $ H(X,Y) + H(Y,Z) + H(X,Z) \geq 2H(X,Y,Z)$

Tags: information-theory, entropy

Let $H$ be the entropy function and $X,Y,Z$ random variables, show that $ H(X,Y) + H(Y,Z) + H(X,Z) \geq 2 H(X,Y,Z)$

I have tried to use some identities like $H(U,V) = H(U) + H(V|U)$  then

$$H(X,Y,Z) = H(X,Y)+ H(Z|X,Y)$$

$$H(X,Y,Z) = H(X,Z) + H(Y|X,Z)$$

Then I should show that $H(Z|X,Y) + H(Y|X,Z) \leq H(Y,Z)$ but I don't know how to proceed, any idea would be very appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that 
$$
\begin{align}
H(Y,Z) &\geq H(Y,Z|X)\\
&= H(Y|Z,X) + H(Z|X)\\
&\geq H(Y|Z,X) + H(Z|X,Y),
\end{align}
$$
with the inequalities following due to conditioning on a random variable can only reduce entropy